# Heroku 503 error

Tags: java, heroku, gradle

Heroku is crashing with no direct error message. Here's the logs:

```
2017-02-20T18:27:08.194304+00:00 app[web.1]: Hello World
2017-02-20T18:27:08.512366+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-02-20T18:27:08.489335+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2017-02-20T18:27:09.590397+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=x.herokuapp.com request_id=59533920-38d9-426f-a7e0-c32d667b8d49 fwd="94.187.7.67" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-02-20T18:27:10.538493+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=x.herokuapp.com request_id=30fdd320-7ea6-4eb5-b3fa-8cf8c4240a21 fwd="94.187.7.67" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Nothing changes with `heroku logs -n 1000`
Here's my code:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Hello World");
  }

}
```

Procfile:

```
web: java -jar build/libs/app-name-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Build.gradle:

```
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.4'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

task stage(dependsOn: ['build', 'clean'])
build.mustRunAfter clean

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '),
                'Main-Class': com.mypackage.Main
        )
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
```

I can see that `Hello World` is being printed. But why is it crashing afterwards?

I am using Gradle with IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: There should be a more descriptive error further up in the logs. Can you run `heroku logs -n 1000` and share it?

Comment: @codefinger I just found this :Error: Unable to access jarfile build/libs/myAppName-1.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar

Comment: @codefinger hmm... It's not there...

Comment: Run `heroku run ls build/libs/` to confirm it's on Heroku

Comment: @codefinger It's not on Heroku

Comment: Well that's a problem. How are you deploying? `git push` or `heroku deploy:jar`?

Comment: @codefinger `git push heroku master`

Comment: What type of app is this (Spring Boot, Grails, Ratpack, etc)? You're going to have to provide a lot more info in the description.

Comment: I'm using Gradle on IntelliJ.

Comment: try this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-gradle-apps-on-heroku

Comment: @codefinger that's what I followed.

Comment: this is going no where. i can't read your mind. post your `build.gradle` in the desc or something.

Comment: @codefinger I didn't expect it to be a problem with my code but rather with the procfile. Edited

Comment: @codefinger so can you give me a hypothesis on why my jar file is missing from heroku? I did do a `git add ...` then a `git commit` then a `git push heroku master`, but for some reason it's still not there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is the application is not a web application.

Consider the content of the `Procfile`:

```
web: java -jar build/libs/app-name-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The first word is `web` which suggests to Heroku that you try to deploy a web application. But the application is not a web application according to its code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }

}
```

The application doesn't run any web server awaiting an HTTP connection on 80 or 8080 port. The application just prints "Hello World" to the standard output and exits (because the end of program reached).

```
2017-02-20T18:27:08.489335+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
```

The web application is suposed to be waiting for incomming connections. It must not reach the end unless a human stops it.

You can generate a template of a web application using [this generator](http://start.spring.io/). The application will use embedded apache tomcat (that will act as the web server of the application) and spring-boot to bootstrap the web application infrastructure. [Here](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) is short tutorial on how to write Hello World application on spring-boot. It deploys and works on Heroku.

Comment: D'oh! I will award you the bounty when I can